# tracking the Corda flows

Tags: corda

Can you describe a way to track flows at the StateMachineManager directly from a Corda service - not via an RPC client?

In particular I'm looking for a way analogous to the vault tracking and querying with the VaultService provided by AppServiceHub.

Thanks, Manuel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Corda 4.x, there is no API for accessing the node's state machine from a `ServiceHub` or `AppServiceHub`.